# I skipped the downloading part in the final part of Ubuntu installation. What did I miss?

Tags: 16.04, laptop, downloads

I was in a hurry while installing Ubuntu and saw the option to skip the downloads so I directly installed it with the basic stuff. Does the stuff that I skipped affect performance or anything else?

Comment: Did you hit the skip button or did you uncheck the download updates during install option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it boots and gets to Unity (the graphical desktop environment), then you should be fine. If you skipped and it works great, it must be a built-in program. You could ask what they were and just get them using the `sudo apt-get install [package here]` command.

Comment: yup it worked, seems im ok then :D

Comment: "You could ask what they were". Ask *who*?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a few ways.

1. You can hit "Search your computer" -> and click on "Software Updater"
2. Open terminal, and type `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

Both will get the remaining packages.

Comment: nailed it, thx alot!